# function with if else statements not working?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, if-statement

Could someone please tell me why this isn't working? I've tried varying the structure alot, but it just seems not matter what I put, when the if else statements are applied, it stops working.

```
    function wordSplit(){
        var sentence = document.getElementById("two").value;
        var userWords=sentence.split(" ");
        while(t<userWords.length){
            alert(userWords[t]);
            t++
        };
        x = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < userWords.length; x++){
            y = 0;
            for (var y = 0; y < vocab.length; y++){

                if (y<vocab.length) {
                    alert("y is less than vocab")
                };
                else if (vocab[y] == userWords[x]){
                    alert("y is equal to x")
                };
                else if(y<vocab.length) {
                    alert("y is less than vocab 2")
                };
                else if (y == vocab.length){
                    alert(" y is equal to vocab length")
                };
                else if (y == 0)
                {
                    alert("y is equal to zero)
                };

            };


        };
    };
```

Comment: Remove the semicolons. The syntax is `if() { } else { }`.

Comment: There are no semicolons between if /else.

Comment: Add a `"` between zero and )

Comment: Also, when you say "stops working", I say you need to start debugging your code with a console so you can get proper error messages.

Comment: Even the syntax highlighting on SO shows (one of ) the problems....

Comment: Don't use the Console - use the Debugger, e.g. in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing the quotes in your last alert:

```
alert("y is equal to zero)
```

Plus as the comments have said - remove the semicolons between `if/else`.

```
            if (y<vocab.length) {
                alert("y is less than vocab")
            }
            else if (vocab[y] == userWords[x]){
                alert("y is equal to x")
            }
            else if(y<vocab.length) {
                alert("y is less than vocab 2")
            }
            else if (y == vocab.length){
                alert(" y is equal to vocab length")
            }
            else if (y == 0)
            {
                alert("y is equal to zero")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
            if (y<vocab.length) {
                alert("y is less than vocab")
            };
            else if (vocab[y] == userWords[x]){
                alert("y is equal to x")
            };
            else if(y<vocab.length) {
                alert("y is less than vocab 2")
            };
            else if (y == vocab.length){
                alert(" y is equal to vocab length")
            };
            else if (y == 0)
            {
                alert("y is equal to zero)
            };
```

Should be this (note the semicolons and the closing "):

```
            if (y<vocab.length) {
                alert("y is less than vocab");
            }
            else if (vocab[y] == userWords[x]){
                alert("y is equal to x");
            }
            else if(y<vocab.length) {
                alert("y is less than vocab 2");
            }
            else if (y == vocab.length){
                alert(" y is equal to vocab length");
            }
            else if (y == 0)
            {
                alert("y is equal to zero");
            }
```

Please note the lack of closing `"` on your final `if else` alert. Also, semicolons (`;`) don't go at the end of conditional statements.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick edit to your code with assumptions on intended result:

```
function wordSplit() {

    var sentence = document.getElementById("two").value;
    var userWords=sentence.split(" ");
    var t = 0;

    while( t < userWords.length) {
        console.log(userWords[t]);
        t++;
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < userWords.length; x++) {
      var y = vocab.indexOf(userWords[x]);
      if (y == -1) {
        console.log(userWords[x] + ' is not found in vabulary list');
      } else {
        console.log(userWords[x] + ' is found in vabulary list');
      }
    }
}
```